# How to convert Character array to Set

Tags: java

How do I add a list of chars into a set?
The code below doesn't seem to work.

```
HashSet<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>(
        new Character[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}
    );
```

The error that I'm seeing is

> The constructor HashSet(Character[]) is undefined

I tried both, Character[] and char[], but neither is working.

Comment: Pass it a collection, not an array. `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'));`

Comment: And you may also omit the ```new Character[]``` and just pass the literal: ```new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList({'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}));```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First convert the `Character` array into `List` and then use [HashSet<>()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet-java.util.Collection-) constructor to convert into `Set`

```
List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(new Character[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'});
Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>(chars);
System.out.println(charSet);
```

or you can directly use `Arrays.asList`

```
Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u','y'));
```

Form [jdk-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#of-E...-) there are `Set.of` methods available to create immutable objects

```
Set<Character> chSet = Set.of('a','e','i','o','u','y');
```

You can also create unmodifiable Set by using `Collections`

```
Set<Character> set2 = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[] {'a','e','i','o','u'})));
```

By using `Arrays.stream`

```
Character[] ch = new Character[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
Set<Character> set = Arrays.stream(ch).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}));
```

Comment: Code-only answers can often be flagged as 'low quality'! Maybe add a few words of explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Since Set is a part of the Collection package in Java. Therefore the Array can be converted into the Set with the help of Collections.addAll() method.

```
 // Crate an Empty Set
 Set<T> set = new HashSet<>(); 
  
  // Add the Character array to set 
  Collections.addAll(set, Arrays.toCharacter( new Character[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'}));
```